# T-shaped polygons

Tags: general-topology, geometry, optimization, computational-geometry, pattern-recognition

Is there any coefficient that can indicate T-shaped polygons ?

Examples of T-shaped polygons:

[image]

Comment: What the... working on OCR?

Comment: Not really, but ... I might be tempted. Actually I am working on a GIS case where we would be glad to have any indication of features shaped in a T-design. 
I very well know this is a long-shot and probably a question to difficult to answer, but I any piece of advise might suit me well, let's just say I am brainstorming SE.

Comment: There must be something, something to set aside T-shaped polygons... There must be !

Comment: Makes me think of [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), although I'm not sure that's a reasonable direction. Will your T-shapes be rotated arbitrarily, or do they only count as T if they are aligned like T?

Comment: Oh, they can be rotated arbitrarily.

Comment: Your features are really polygons? Because many things that I can think of, like e.g. least squares approximation, would work better for sets of points instead of polygons. So if these polygons were obtained from points, it might well be that they cause more problems than they solve. If your features are really polygons to start with, I'm not sure whether filling them with points will be of any use, but it's at least something I'm considering.

Comment: @MvG : I can transform my polygons to lines, so if you have some ideas I would be pleased to take note of them.

Comment: Still thinking, will post if I find something that looks promising. Lines are not that much better than polygons. I added two tags, [tag:pattern-recognition] because you want to recognize T-shaped patterns (which [might be closer to the idea of this tag than many existing questions in that category](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6588/35416)) and  [tag:optimization] because many approaches will try finding the closest (i.e. optimal) “proper” T before deciding whether it's close enough. I have doubts about [tag:general-topology] but don't know enough about that field to remove the tag.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brainstorming answer to a brainstorming question… I'm not happy with this answer myself, and hope that me posting this answer doesn't prevent someone likely to give a better answer from reading your question in the first place.

You could start by identifying two points with maximal distance from one another, which you can obtain in linear time from the convex hull. Then look for a third point which is a maximal distance away from the line spanned by these two. If it is a T, you should have the three endpoints of its lines. Try all possible ways to connect one of the three points to the midpoint of the other two, then check how close your polygon is to the resulting shape by e.g. integrating some simple cost function or some such. It should be possible to adapt the shoelace formula to compute such integrals in reasonable time. This approach will however be rather sensitive to curls at the ends of the lines, like depicted in your right image.

To avoid that, perhaps don't use the extremal points, but instead try to find a best fit to the shape as a whole. Unfortunately, I can see no way to turn this into a linear problem, so instead of a simple least squares approximation or something like this you'd be in the domain of non-linear optimization. So you might look for the best-fitting set of T-describing parameters (orientation angle, size, aspect ratio, bar width) using some common non-linear optimization technique, with all the trouble about local optima that usually entails.

I also know that [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) and its generalizations are sometimes used to detect shapes in images. At some other point, I've heard about a thing called a chamfer matching, though that appears to be rather pixel-oriented. None of this sounds like an easy to implement solution.

Comment: +1, thanks for the ideas, the first one looks like a simple enough algorithm to implement, although running it on a high number of polygones might take time.